# git tmbundle for textmate - where is the checkout for the branch?

Tags: git, textmate, textmatebundles

i'm actually using the git tmbundle for textmate.
really useful!

unfortunately i miss the checkout, so i can't "merge" the branch to the master.

anyone know where is it?
thanks in advance :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Isn't what the "[`SwitchToBranch` command](http://github.com/jcf/git-tmbundle/blob/master/Commands/Switch%20to%20Branch.tmCommand)" is supposed to do?